# [Vue warn]: Prop "zoom" expects a two-way binding type. (found in component: <map>)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

First and foremost, thank you for taking the time to help!

I'm trying to implement vue-google-maps into my website and I keep getting these errors. What am I doing wrong? I know this has to be an easy fix, something I am overlooking.

```
[Vue warn]: Prop "zoom" expects a two-way binding type. (found in component: <map>)
[Vue warn]: Prop "center" expects a two-way binding type. (found in component: <map>)
```

**I'm calling the map in my template with this:**

```
<map :center="center" :zoom="7"></map>
```

**Here's my script at the bottom of my main template:**

```
<script>
import { Map } from 'vue-google-maps'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
  }
  components: {
    Map
  }
}
</script>
```

This is how I usually import templates and they work fine, I did it with Keen-ui and it worked perfectly, but for some reason I can't get the vue-google-maps module to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working finally.. Apparently in the docs that it was set to twoWay: true, which requires that you use something like :center.sync. After adding .sync it started working.

Before:

```
<map :center="center" :zoom="7"></map>
```

After:

```
<map :center.sync="center" :zoom.sync="7"></map>
```

Comment: You beat me by a second, haha!